# Spring - Annotation Based Controller - RequestMapping based on query string

Tags: spring, annotations

In Spring annotation-based controller, is it possible to map different query strings using `@RequestMapping` to different methods?

For example

```
@RequestMapping("/test.html?day=monday")
public void writeMonday() {
}


@RequestMapping("/test.html?day=tuesday")
public void writeTuesday() {
}
```

Answer (score 80):

Yes, you can use the [params](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params()) element:

```
@RequestMapping("/test.html", params = "day=monday")
public void writeMonday() {
}

@RequestMapping("/test.html", params = "day=tuesday")
public void writeTuesday() {
}
```

You can even map based on the *presence* or *absence* of a param:

```
@RequestMapping("/test.html", params = "day")
public void writeSomeDay() {
}

@RequestMapping("/test.html", params = "!day")
public void writeNoDay() {
}
```

Comment: This showed syntax error for me(on Spring 3), but the following worked.

@RequestMapping(value="/test.html", params = "day=monday")

Comment: if i have multiple params in url then what to do ??

Answer (score 53):

or you could do something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/test.html")
public void writeSomeDay(@RequestParam String day) {
   // code to handle "day" comes here...
}
```