# learning Spring's @RequestBody and @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm editing a web project that uses Spring and I need to adding some of Spring's annotations.  Two of the ones I'm adding are [@RequestBody](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) and [@RequestParam](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html). I've been poking around a little and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454689/spring-annotation-based-controller-requestmapping-based-on-query-string), but I still don't completely understand how to use these annotations. Could anyone provide an example?

Comment: There are good examples in the documentation, for both [`@RequestMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) and [`@RequestBody`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody)

Answer (score 18):

Controller example:

```
@Controller
class FooController {
    @RequestMapping("...")
    void bar(@RequestBody String body, @RequestParam("baz") baz) {
        //method body
    }
}
```

**[@RequestBody](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody):** variable body will contain the body of the HTTP request

**[@RequestParam](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam):** variable baz will hold the value of request parameter baz

Comment: Can a method have multiple @RequestBody params?

Comment: No it cannot, there is only one HTTP Body, so there can only be one RequestBody variable

Answer (score 3):

**@RequestParam** annotated parameters get linked to specific Servlet request parameters. Parameter values are converted to the declared method argument type. 
This annotation indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter.

*For example Angular request for Spring RequestParam(s) would look like that:*

```
$http.post('http://localhost:7777/scan/l/register', {params: {"username": $scope.username, "password": $scope.password, "auth": true}}).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        ...
                    })

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", value = "/register")
public Map<String, String> register(Model uiModel,
                                    @RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, boolean auth,
                                    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {...
```

**@RequestBody** annotated parameters get linked to the HTTP request body. Parameter values are converted to the declared method argument type using HttpMessageConverters. 
This annotation indicates a method parameter should be bound to the body of the web request.

*For example Angular request for Spring RequestBody would look like that:*

```
$scope.user = {
            username: "foo",
            auth: true,
            password: "bar"
        };    
$http.post('http://localhost:7777/scan/l/register', $scope.user).
                        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            ...
                        })

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", value = "/register")
public Map<String, String> register(Model uiModel,
                                    @RequestBody User user,
                                    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {...
```

Hope this helps.