# Required String parameter 'text' is not present

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to send a string from my view to my controller, but I keep getting the error that "text" is not present.

this is my javascript

```
$scope.sendMsg = function(){
        console.log($scope.my.message);

        data = {"text" : $scope.my.message};

        $http({
            method:'POST',
            data:data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            url:'/post-stuff'
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });     
    }
```

My rest controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/post-stuff", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<PostTextResult> postStuff(@RequestParam(value= "text") String text){
        System.out.println(text);
        return new ResponseEntity<PostTextResult>(stuff.postTextContent(text), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Try stringifying the data before you send

Comment: A `@RequestParam` value is extracted from query parameters. You don't have any. `data` is the body, as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change in frontend in your current `data` to:

```
data = {params:{"text" : $scope.my.message}};
```

Spring need to know that request has parameters.

Or you can try to change the in backend in your controller `@RequestParam(value= "text") String text` to `@RequestBody String text`

*Check out the difference between [RequestBody and RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039709/what-is-difference-between-requestbody-and-requestparam)*

Comment: Thanks. i changed it to @requestbody

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether there is a way that Spring can de-json `{"text" : "some text"}` into the raw string `"some text"`. However `@RequestParam` is used for parameters within URLs (`http://foo.com/post-stuff?text=text+here`).

`POST`ed data is sent in the body, so you'll need to use the `@RequestBody` annotation. And since the body is a more complex type, I'd use a class that makes it easy to extract the value:

```
static class TextHolder {
  private String text;  // < name matters
  // getter+setter omitted
}

public ResponseEntity<PostTextResult> postStuff(@RequestBody TextHolder text) {
    System.out.println(text.getText());
    return new ResponseEntity<PostTextResult>(stuff.postTextContent(text.getText()), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```