# Trouble getting data from REST http service using requests package

Tags: python, web, python-requests

This works fine, I can get data returned:

```
r = urllib2.Request("http://myServer.com:12345/myAction")
data = json.dumps(q) #q is a python dict
r.add_data(data)
r=urllib2.urlopen(r)
```

But doing the same with requests package fails:

```
r=requests.get("http://myServer.com:12345/myAction", data=q)
r.text #This will return a message that says method is not allowed.
```

It works if I make it a post request:        `r=requests.post("http://myServer.com:12345/myAction", data=json.dumps(q))`

But why?

Comment: Try `params` instead of `data` for `requests.get` call

Comment: Same error. But if i switch to requests.post(), it works magically. (Keeping data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`urllib2.urlopen` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

> the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a GET when the data parameter is provided.

This way, `r=urllib2.urlopen(r)` is also making a POST request. That is why your `requests.get` does not work, but `requests.post` does.

Comment: Does that mean the server was set up to only receive POST requests?

Comment: Yes. Seems like this endpoint does not accept `GET` requests. Maybe it can receive also `PATCH`, `DELETE` or other request methods. So I am not sure that it is accepts `POST` methods *only*, the more correct statement is that this endpoint does not accept `GET`

Comment: Why does the urllib2.urlopen force the request to be POST when data parameter is provided? Can't you have a http server that serves you data based on a request, without modifying anything on the server? Isn't that a classic GET request?

Comment: GET request does not have a body, it only accepts query parameters

Comment: what is the difference between body and parameters

Comment: Parameters are part of url. Request body is a part of request. You may find the differences in the docs or in the questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039709/what-is-difference-between-requestbody-and-requestparam

Answer (score 0):

Set up a session

```
import session

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get("http://myServer.com:12345/myAction", data=q)
print r.content (<- or could us r.raw)
```