# HTTP Security: @RequestParam and @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-framework-beans

Which is more secure between `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody` in Spring Framework application?

I am using `@PostMapping` in backend.
I am using `@RequestParam` as well as `@RequestBody`.

`@RequestParam` for few request parameters, one or two.

`@RequestBody` for large request as an object with multiple fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think they're used for completely different purposes

Comment: Define "secure" in this context.

Comment: Secure - Not easily intercepted or hacked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between @RequestBody and @RequestParam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039709/what-is-difference-between-requestbody-and-requestparam)

Comment: I already read that. There is no mention of security anywhere. So, is it nothing to do with security whichever we use?

Comment: Assuming SSL, while **in transit** it doesn't matter.  However, consider a URL such as `https://example.com/login?userId=jdoe&password=god`.  This URL will be in the browser history, and could also be bookmarked, so easily visible to anybody that gains access to the same device. Also, some systems will log the URL for auditing purposes inadvertently exposing sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest there shouldn't be much difference if we consider security aside from what Andrew already mentioned. I just want to add, that using RequestParam for POST calls is rather a bad practice. I think you should pay more attention to which request method you are using and consider overall structure of your REST API.

Comment: Thanks but how is it a bad practice. Can you Explain?