# (Spring, AngularJS)I don't know why it is NULL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring

I wanna send user's email to check duplicate

This is my Back Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/public/checkDuplicate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getCnt(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value="usrEmail", required=false) String usrEmail){
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

And this is my Front Controller

```
$scope.user.usrEmail = $scope.usrEmail;
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: './api/v1/public/checkDuplicate',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: angular.toJson($scope.usrEmail)
};
```

And this is my View

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="usr_Email"
       ng-model="usrEmail" ng-required="true" 
       ng-keypress="checkDuplicate()">
```

When I checked using 'console.log', Front Controller can get user's email properly.
But in Back Controller, RequestParam has nothing, just NULL without Error Code except 'NullPointerException'.

It isn't communication error I think.
Are there something I missed?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey @zzangs33, i answered again. please check

Comment: @SangramBadi -- please don't poke OP to check your answer. If it solved the problem, they will apparently upvote/accept it.

Comment: When the client is POSTing the data as an object or a string, the server receives it in RequestBody and not RequestParam. Use RequestBody and see what object you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the `@RequestParam` that you are using in Back Controller as it is linked to request params. It should be `@RequestBody` which is linked to the HTTP request body. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980438/2978985) for more info.

Now you can change your code like below -

Back Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/public/checkDuplicate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getCnt(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestBody Object userReqObj){
            HashMap<String, Object> userMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) userReqObj;
            String userEmail = userMap.get("usrEmail");
            //logic goes here...
    }
```

Front Controller

```
var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: './api/v1/public/checkDuplicate',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
             'usrEmail' : $scope.usrEmail
       }
    };
```

Comment: I send Object's JSON as RequestBody Map<Object, String> map, and then it works! I don't know why it isn't work when I send only String as RequestParam....

Comment: @zzangs33 For `@RequestParam` you have to send the string as request params like `./api/v1/public/checkDuplicate?usrEmail=some@email.com`

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) for `$http` config object. For the key data, it says:

> `data – {string|Object}` – Data to be sent as the request message data.

This means that `data` can be an object or a string. In your case, you're sending it as a string, which makes sense, but you forgot to mention the name of the parameter in it. The `data` in your code should be the following:

```
data: 'usrEmail=' + $scope.usrEmail // there is no need of angular.toJson here
```

This correctly signifies the name of the parameter as `usrEmail`. But to avoid the confusion, you can always use an object to specify the data:

```
data: {
  usrEmail: $scope.usrEmail
}
```

Comment: I tried changing code as you write, It didn't work too. and I also tried sending RequestBody as map`$scope.user.usrEmail = $scope.usrEmail; ~~ data : angular.toJson($scope.user)`

Comment: @zzangs33 -- What's the error? Did you try to make data as string?

Comment: `public ResponseEntity<Object> getCnt(
   HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response,
   @RequestParam(value="usrEmail", required=false) String usrEmail)`

Comment: `var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: './api/v1/public/checkDuplicate',
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: { 
       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
      'usrEmail' : $scope.usrEmail
     };`

Comment: I only changed code in the JS. but it is still NULL

Comment: @zzangs33 -- On JS side, your code was correct, except in the `data`, instead of `angular.toJson($scope.usrEmail)` you need to write `'usrEmail=' + $scope.usrEmail`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I send Object's JSON as RequestBody Map<Object, String> map, and then it works! I don't know why it isn't work when I send only String as RequestParam....

Answer (score 1):

Send your data from angularjs like below

```
$scope.user.usrEmail = $scope.usrEmail;
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: './api/v1/public/checkDuplicate',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        data: {
             'usrEmail' : $scope.usrEmail
       }
    };
```

Use RequestBody annotaion to get email as you are passing data from body. and need to create a Bean class for user.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/public/checkDuplicate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getCnt(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestBody User usrEmail){
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

**OR**

If you want to use PathVariable then you need to pass email from your URL in angularjs.

```
 url: './api/v1/public/checkDuplicate/'+$scope.usrEmail
```

Then you need to `use @PathValiable('usrEmail')` in your controller and `@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/public/checkDuplicate/{usrEmail}"`

Comment: `'usrEmail' : $scope.usrEmail` , `@RequestParam(value="usrEmail", required=false) String usrEmail)`

Comment: then you need to create a bean for user, which may conatins getter setter method of email. Or you can pass email is from URL and can use PathVariable annotaion

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/doc/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ResponseEntity<Object> getList(
   HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response,
   @RequestParam(value="formId", required=false) String formId,   
   @RequestParam(value="currentPage", defaultValue="1", required=false) int currentPage,
   @RequestParam(value="docTitle", required=false) String docTitle,
   @RequestParam(value="companyId", required=false) String companyId,
   @RequestParam(value="order", required=false) String order)` This code goes well.. but I don't know what is diffrent.

Comment: I send Object's JSON as RequestBody Map<Object, String> map, and then it works! I don't know why it isn't work when I send only String as RequestParam....

Answer (score 1):

you didn't add query parameter in the angular

```
     url: './api/v1/public/checkDuplicate?**usrEmail='+$scope.usrEmail**
```

add this to you code ?usrEmail='+$scope.usrEmail