# I have a problem sending json data to a controller with ajax

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring

I have a problem sending json data to a controller with ajax.

I think I sent the data well but I get the following warn.

org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required int parameter 'bno' is not present]

```
code:400
message:HTTP Status 400 – Bad Requesth1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}HTTP Status 400 – Bad RequestType Status ReportMessage Required int parameter 'bno' is not presentDescription The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
```

I'll show my ajax code

```
var headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/json"
        ,"X-HTTP-Method-Override" : "DELETE"
      };
$.ajax({
          url: root+"/restcmt/"+uid+"/"+cno
              , headers: headers
              , type: 'DELETE'
              , data : JSON.stringify({"bno":bno})
              , beforeSend : function(xhr){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(_csrf_name, _csrf_token);
                }
              , success: function(result){
                  showcmtlist(bno);
              }
              , error: function(request,status,error){
                console.log("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);


                }
          });
```

And my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/{uid}/{cno}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deletecmt(@PathVariable int cno ,@PathVariable String uid,@RequestParam int bno
            ,@AuthenticationPrincipal SecurityCustomUser securityCustomUser) throws Exception{

    }
```

and request payload

```
{"bno":14}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`{"bno": bno}` is in the body of the request.  So your Controller method should be `@RequestBody int bno`.  `@RequestParam` is for servlet request parameters.  i.e: `/uid/cno?bno=14`

difference for reference: [What is difference between @RequestBody and @RequestParam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039709/what-is-difference-between-requestbody-and-requestparam)

Comment: Aha! Thanks to you, I got to know the difference between the two. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the Spring-World request payload should correspond to @RequestBody, e.x:

```
public SomethingElse updateValue(@RequestBody Something value) {
    // ...
}
```

Where "Something" is any POJO.

In order to use @RequestParam, see:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3269

($.ajax Sends `data` property in DELETE body instead of query string)