# Multi part form data is not accepted in the spring boot rest controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http

I want to send multi part form data to my spring boot rest controller.

Below is my code of request handler

```
@PostMapping(value = "/postmultipartformdata" , consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String postFormData(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData) {
    
    return "Welcome to the post method with multi part form data. Printing whatever is present in the body " +  formData;
}
```

However whenever i send the request with form data from postman. I get this response back

```
  "timestamp": "2020-07-02T05:10:40.320+00:00",
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"message": "",
"path": "/postmultipartformdata"
```

Probably i am missing something very simple.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestBody` and also if the content that you are sending is actually a file , map it to a `MultipartFile` object, which in your case might not be needed but since it is not clear from your question the kind of data that you are sending I am including this here, like :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/postmultipartformdata" , consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String postFormData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    yourService.store(file);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Usually we use MultipartFile as a representation of an uploaded file received in a multipart request.

Comment: how is this linked to the question asked?

Comment: He is getting 415 unsupported media type because he is using @RequestBody instead of RequestParam and if it is a multipart file content that he is sending the type should be as such to properly get the file right ?

Comment: I have amended my answer to make my point clear. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestBody` to obtain the wanted part in your multipart request.

So like:

```
@RequestPart LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> formData
```

I also switched to concrete class `LinkedMultiValueMap` since Spring had hard times to instantiate `MultiValueMap`.

Then send the `formData` part with `Content-Type: application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestBody`.
Since it is form data is treated with request param and not with the request body.

Here is how I have corrected it:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/postmultipartformdata", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String postFormData(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> formData) {
        return "Welcome to the post method with multi part form data. Printing whatever is present in the body " + formData;
}
```

command

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/status/postmultipartformdata' \
--form 'a=a' \
--form 'b=b' \
--form 'c=c'
```

output:

```
Welcome to the post method with multi part form data.
Printing whatever is present in the body {a=[a], b=[b], c=[c]}
```

Reference:

[What is difference between @RequestBody and @RequestParam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039709/what-is-difference-between-requestbody-and-requestparam)