# 400 Bad Request when using Spring Boot with localDateTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, iso8601, localdatetime

I am sending a Http POST request to `http://localhost:8080/date` with the body

```
{
    "localDateTime": "2021-06-08T11:39:01"
}
```

(I tried multiple different time formats, always the same error)
to my Java application built with Spring Boot.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@PostMapping(path ="/date",consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
    public String dateTime(@RequestParam(name = "localDateTime") 
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return localDateTime.toString();
    }
}
```

I know it's a little bit tricky with Spring Boot, but I read that the  `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)` annotation should allow it to properly convert the Strings to date objects.

Instead I get the `400 Bad Request` error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Please, remove `consumes="application/json", produces="application/json"`, you are already using the RestController annotation.

Change @RequestParam to @RequestBody, if you want to send JSON as Body. Use @RequestParam for `/date?localDateTime=2021-06-08T11:39:01`.

[What is difference between @RequestBody and @RequestParam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039709/what-is-difference-between-requestbody-and-requestparam)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please, mark it as correct answer to help community find solutions.