# Match request payload and post method

Tags: spring, rest, payload

My back doesn't receive parameters from a mobile app.

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException Required String parameter 'param1' is not present
```

With Chrome DevTools, I can see that the mobile app call my back with these parameters :

```
RequestMethod : POST
Request Payload : param1=toto&param2=titi
Request Headers: Content-Type : application/json
```

I try to retrieve parameters like this :

```
public void method (@RequestParam(name = "param1") String param1, @RequestParam(name = "param2") String param2) {
...
}
```

(I tried with "value" instead of "name")

How can I match the payload that the front sends me, with my back ?
The payload is imposed on me, it is my back that must be modified

Previously, the back was in Jersey, with @FormParam annotation. I switch the back to spring framework, with the use of RequestParam...

Comment: RequestBody & RequestParam both are different https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337350/learning-springs-requestbody-and-requestparam

Comment: @RyuzakiL Thank you for your helpful answer which help me a lot ! ... or not -_-
can you told me HOW I can match this payload with my back ? Without told me some annotations are different...

Comment: Request Headers: Content-Type : application/json seems to be an error, payload doesn't contain json

Comment: @MarcStroebel unfortunately, I don't have choice for Content-Type : it's the front code, not mine, I must compose with these content-type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post resolve my problem to receive a payload in raw with a spring back :
[How to access plain json body in Spring rest controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866996/how-to-access-plain-json-body-in-spring-rest-controller)
(HttpEntity for me)

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestParam`is used for query params, try to catch the raw request body

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public String myMethod(@RequestBody String param) {
    
}
```

The frontend app seems broken... payload format `param1=toto&param2=titi` looks like query params, not a request body... and content type `application/json` also doesn't match...

Comment: try removing the consumes param...

Comment: sorry for my deleted answer. I tried with @RequestBody, with HttpServletRequest... The call my back receive is empty, no parameter is catch...

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was surprised to see what I thought were inconsistencies. I'll talk to the mobile app developer...